# Method of False Position

Tags: numerical-methods

I'm trying to use the Method of false position on the functions below to find solutions to within $10^{-5}$

(1) $f(x) = \ln (x-1) + \cos(x-1) = 0$, for $1.3 \leq x \leq2$

and

(2) $2x \cos(2x) -(x-2)^2 = 0$, for  $[2,3]$ and $[3,4]$

I am trying to do this without using a computer program, and am stuck.
Thanks

Comment: Concerning function 1, what are you asking here different from [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105568/secant-method-for-fx-lnx-1-cosx-1-interval-1-3-leq-x-leq-2) of yours?

Comment: They are using different methods

Comment: Thank you! I had *wrongly* thought it was the same method, just different names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Evaluate $f(1.3)$ and $f(2)$.  (You will want to use a calculator.)
2. Now, given just these two points, suppose $f$ is like a straight line through these two points.  Where (i.e. for what $x$) would $f(x)=0$?  (The $x$ you find this way, by pretending $f$ is a straight line inside the interval, is the *false position*.)
3. Evaluate $f(x)$ for this $x$ (using the correct $f$ again now).
4. You now have a smaller interval (either $[1.3,x]$ or $[x,2]$ -- whichever one contains a sign change for $f$) which you know contains the solution to $f(x)=0$.
5. Go back to step 1, but now use your smaller interval instead of $[1.3,2]$.